# How to check the content from a Map?

Tags: java

I have a Problem with a Map in Java.
The Code looks like this:

```
Map<Object, Object> test = myClass.getMap();
int value = (int) test.get(myID);
```

When I reach the second line I get a:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now I'm asking myself how to debug this and find yout why this is not working? I'm quite sure that all keys and values are in this map.

How to print out the whole map so I can search if the key is available? (Its a very long map)

Or what is the right way to find the problem?

Comment: Can you please also post the stack trace?

Comment: Check whether `test` is `null`.  Check whether `test.get(myID)` is `null`.

Comment: First, make sure that `myClass.getMap() != null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems here :

1. `Map test` could be `null`.
2. You cannot cast from `Object` to `int`. You need to cast it to `Integer`.

I believe the below line shouldn't compile:

```
int value = (int) test.get(myID);
```

as `get()` returns `Object` , and you are trying to cast it to primitive `int`. Even if you cast it to `Integer` :

```
int value = (Integer) test.get(myID); // assume auto-unwrapping here
```

The above code will throw NPE , if `get(myID);` is `null`.
You need to use :

```
Integer value = (Integer) test.get(myID);
```

You can use `test.containsKey(myID)` , to check for key. Finally do something like this :

```
if(test!=null && test.containsKey(myID))
    Integer value = (Integer) test.get(myID);
```

You should use [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) in your `Map` though.

Comment: I agree, most likely `test` is null. If the object happens to be an Integer, AFAIK a cast to int would succeed though.

Answer (score 5):

you can do `map.containsKey(key)` to check if the key exists

The reason for NPE, is that the value for `myId` in the `map` was `null` and you are trying to convert it to primitive `int` (which **cannot hold** non null values). Changing it to below statement will avoid the exception (unless the map `test` itself is `null`)

```
Integer value = (Integer ) test.get(myID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE with an integrated debugger: put a breakpoint somewhere after the map was instantiated and after it was initialized and see effectively what's inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer you'r question if you want to print the map:

```
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : test.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + " Value:" + entry.getValue());
}
```

However the `containsKey()` method should be probably what you rather need.